# Is it possible to add custom PR review lists to my inbox in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, pull-request

In my pull requests page of azure devops I have a few custom lists, 'Assigned to Dev' and 'Assigned to QA'. These work because part of the branch policy in the repo I work auto assigns a group of QA members and a group of Dev team members to review every PR -- that way each PR gets reviewed by at least one side of the SDLC. There's also the inbox shortcut icon in the upper right. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to put my two custom lists in that drop down (to reduce clicks to see outstanding PRs)

[image: Azure Devops view of PR management page]

Answer (score 1):

There's no such a built-in feature in Azure DevOps.

[A custom pull request view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/view-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#define-a-custom-pull-request-view) cannot be displayed in `My Work` hub (Upper right inbox you mentioned).
They have different logic and use different queries in `My Pull requests` page and `My Work` hub.

You can try to check whether the [Pull Requests extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Pull%20Request&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Repos&sortBy=Relevance) in marketplace meet your requirements. If no existing extension meet your requirements, then I'm afraid that you have to write your own extension to achieve that.